# Installed version 12.04 and it works. Do I really need a newer version...?

Tags: security, support

I have been unable to install 14.04. I was able to install 12.04. But, I was advised to install 14.01/14.10.

Do I really need to install a newer version if 12.04 works? Are there security issues with 12.04 or some other reason why I must use a more recent version?

Answer (score 1):

[12.04 is supported till April 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), so I also will be using it on my old PCs till then for its 2d desktop. Will probably go Lubuntu then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 12.04, you are still in support, see:

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2011/10/21/ubuntu-12-04-to-feature-extended-support-period-for-desktop-users/

However, if you are using a variant such as Lubuntu, you will no longer be receiving security updates so ought to consider an upgrade.

Of course, no-one will stop you using an out of support version of Linux; your computer won't suddenly cease to function. However, it isn't protected. If someone manages to gain control of your computer through an unpatched security vulnerability, there is no help for you and it makes everyone else more vulnerable.